# How to set a view to be controller like button for Accessibility

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, view, accessibility

I need my view to be found when TalkBack is set to find controllers.
View:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clInformative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: lol, very simple, "I need my view to be found when TalkBack is set to find controllers."

In the comment below, @Benny understood my question and helped me a lot with his answer, I didn't understand why you rate me negative. If possible undo this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `AccessibilityDelegateCompat` to your `clInformative` view and assign the role of a button. For example:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(clInformative, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
  @Override
  public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
    info.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
  }
});
```